# MFA Button is grayed out

Tags: amazon-web-services

Good day all, we have AWS account almost set up. What is left is to activate MFA, but the button that activates is grayed out and unclickable. Through the user tab we manually assigned MFA and when we login it asked us to insert the code, which is nice. But button that manages MFA is grayed out as shown in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to be logged in as root user to change that setting. Even an user with Administrator access would find it disabled.

Administrator can activate the MFA by clicking on the particular user, then under the 'Security Credentials' there is a 'Assigned MFA device' setting. If it indicates 'No' then MFA device is not set up for that user. Administrator/root user could change this setting to set up MFA device for that particular user.

Credit-Shazic
https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate/discussion/-KYMx91XRAyy_6cDfj5F/manage-mfa-is-disabled

Answer (score 0):

What I did was in my root account I created a IAM user with full admin access.

I logged in as this user then went to

IAM -> users -> click the admin user -> Click the security credentials tab -> look under sign-in credentials

Where it says Assigned MFA device is what you want to edit I think.

Not sure if this if this is the best way to do this but it's what I did.  Not sure why that button doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To see that button enabled, you have to login as root user. Actually this button says: "Activate multi-factor authentication (MFA) on your AWS root account to add another layer of protection to help keep your account secure." So, this is just for root account.
Now, a user with admin privileges (not root) even can activate other user's (or self) MFA. To do this, we have to select that particular user from user's tab and under security credentials, activate MFA.